# Java: How to get high and low 16bit values from a 32bit HEX?

Tags: java

Need a solution on how to perform the following: receive a decimal value, convert it to 32-bit Hex, then separate that 32-bit hex and get high 16-bit and low 16-bit values. I have been digging around net and cannot find much info.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  If I were you I would first write the routine to convert to hex.

Comment: Do you mean an instance of type Decimal? Also, what's a 32-bit hex? Are you saying that you want an 8-digit hexadecimal string?

Comment: I have a distinct feeling this might be another case of somebody referring to a value by its human readable representation. By saying "32bit HEX", do you actually mean a 32-bit integer, or a string representation of such an integer?

Comment: You need to define the problem space more clearly. _"receive a decimal value"_ - is this a non-integer? If so, what strategy does the business logic dictate for converting a non-integer to an integer value? What does hex have to do with this? There is an important difference between a value and its representation.

Comment: I've always found it funny when people use the term "business logic" with something that might have nothing to do with business at all. As if all programming was about business. What happened to the science of it?

Comment: Actually looking for a 32-bit HEX. Receiving an integer as a Java primitive data type.

Comment: Something like here: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Comment: @Matti: `s/business/domain/g` happy?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Quite happy.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you are converting to hex but to turn a 32-bit value straight into two 16-bit values.

```
int x = ...
short high = x >> 16;
short low = x & 0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 4):

I expect this is a homework problem. Accordingly, I will give you information that can help you solve it rather than a solution.

1. Convert the number to hexadecimal. This can be done with the Integer's `toHexString()` method.
2. Add enough zeroes to the left to make it eight characters long (8 hexadecimal characters represent 32 bits). You can do this by adding zeroes one by one in a loop until it's 8 characters long, or (better approach) just add 7 zeroes to the left and only deal with the rightmost 8 characters.
3. Take the the rightmost 4 characters as the lower 16 bits and the 4 characters immediately to the left of that as the higher 16 bits. This can be done with the String's `substring()` method along with `length()` and some simple subtraction.

Comment: Hi Kindall, toHexString method will convert to 16bit Hex, which is not what's required. For example: 32-bit Hex for 10000 = 461C4000, toHexString producing: 2710. Adding zeros to it will result in 00002710.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Hex for 10000 is most assuredly not 461C4000!

Comment: It is, in 32-bit Representation. 2710 is in 16-bit. Point of reference: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Comment: Wait... you wanted the hex equivalent of a FLOATING-POINT value but didn't bother saying so? ARRRRRRGH... why would you leave that out of your original question?

Comment: Well, in my case it is not a floating point, but a decimal. I am able to produce this HEX representation. Getting High 16-bit and Low 16-Bit - would it be simply splitting the resulting representation on two substrings?

Comment: Yeah, splitting the hex string would probably be the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Some APIs you might find useful:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String, int)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)
http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html